# Shadow DOM and ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, shadow-dom

I am using web components in my application. And in a web component, I need to insert a react component. Web Component has Shadow DOM. When I try to render the react component using following I get the error.

```
comp = React.createElement(ReactElem, {
    config: config,
    onRender: handleRender
});

ReactDOM.render(comp , self.shadowRoot.querySelector('#app1'));
```

Error

```
target container is not a dom element
```

I tried to use `content` of Web component API but then it gets rendered on top rather inside component. Any leads how can make React component to get rendered inside shadow DOM?

Comment: Even if it uses a Shadow DOM you can get the generated HTML and load it there, or am I missing something here?

Comment: what is "app1"? don't you mean `"#app1"`?

Comment: @Supersharp It's a web component.

Comment: no..it is div#app1...my bad..it is basically inside shadowDOM

Comment: @juancab ShadowDOM is not accesible to external libs directly. Even if you access and provide them to react, refs/events are not properly getting set.

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/examples/webcomponents/index.html)? It's an example of how both Web Components and a React Component interoperate

Comment: Thanks. Found that I made a small mistake. My DOM was 2 levels down in shadow and slot element was mentioned at only one place

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to insert it inside the shadow DOM of a web component, first select the component (e.g. with `querySelector`) and then its containing shadow (`shadowRoot`). Simplified example:

```js
// Create React Element.
class Example extends React.Component {
  onClick() {
    console.log('Shadow!')
  }
  render() {
    return(
      <div onClick={this.onClick}>Hello World!</div>
    );
  }
}

// Create web component with target div inside it.
const container = document.createElement('app');
document.body.appendChild(container);

// Add shadow root to component.
const shadow = document.querySelector('app').attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });

// Select the web component, then the shadowRoot.
const target = document.querySelector('app').shadowRoot;

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, target);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: problem is `react` is unable to do all manipulations like click is not working. And also there might be multiple instances of the component and this way I need to call every place

Comment: `onClick` is working for me, updated my answer. What do you mean with "call every place"? That you have to render it every time with `ReactDOM`?

Comment: Thanks. Found that I made a small mistake. My DOM was 2 levels down in shadow and slot element was mentioned at only one place

Comment: FYI: [createShadowRoot is deprecated in favor of attachShadow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/attachShadow)

Comment: Doing similar things but react is not allowed to access hooks, so seems like only pure components are working here. Any workaround for react hooks?

Answer (score 4):

#### Hey my friend, I took the time and crafted this for us:

```js
// ShadowRoot.js

import React from "react";

export class ShadowRoot extends React.Component {

    attachShadow(host) {
        if (host == null) {
            return;
        }
        host.attachShadow({mode: "open"});
        host.shadowRoot.innerHTML = host.innerHTML;
        host.innerHTML = "";
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <span ref={this.attachShadow}>
                {this.props.children}
            </span>
        );
    }

}
```

#### Use it like this:

```js
<ShadowRoot>
    // put stuff here you want inside shadow root
</ShadowRoot>
```

**2 things to consider:**

- the class `React.Component` is working better than the hook equivalent
- the `innerHTML` thing is kinda hacky, and state updates are not working with this component