# Preact web component CSS leaking to host HTML

Tags: css, reactjs, web-component, shadow-dom, preact

Have created a very small web-component using preact ( doesn't do anything yet ). I plan to give people my bundles script and html tag to put on their site.

I'm having an issue with regards to CSS, which I assumed should be fully contained by using web components.

I'm using webpack to bundle the preact application into a single file including js and css.

### My setup

**index.html (the container acting as a static host website for my widget )**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <style>
        h1   {color: blue;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>This is the Host site - should be blue</h1>
    <script src="bundle.js"></script>
    <my-widget></my-widget>

</body>
</html>
```

**app.js ( the component which is the essentially the web component )**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {h} from 'preact';

import register from '@wcd/preact-custom-element';

import './app.css';

class App extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>This is a heading 1 tag- should be pink</h1>
                <button>This is the start of my preact app</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

register(App, 'my-widget', ['my-widget']);
```

**app.css**

```
h1{
    color: pink;
}

button{
    background-color: red;
}
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
    entry: path.resolve(__dirname, "./src/app.js"),
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: "bundle.js"
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js?$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: "babel-loader"
            },
            { test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                  { loader: 'style-loader' },
                  { loader: 'css-loader' }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
            template: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/index.html' ),
            filename: 'index.html'
        }),
        new BundleAnalyzerPlugin()
    ],
    resolve: {
        alias : {
            "react": "preact/compat",
            "react-dom/test-utils": "preact/test-utils",
            "react-dom": "preact/compat",
        }
    }
};
```

### The problem

As you can see in the image below, my pink styling has leaked in to the outer DOM and changed the `<h1>` tag on the host website. Obviously this is a problem as I don't want my web-component to be changing the site its used on. Its also not picking up any styles of its own so all in all very strange behavior if you ask me.

[image]

Any one had any similar behavior or can point out where I'm being stupid?

Comment: assign a class to your outer `<div class="plugin">` and 'namespace' (add a 'prefix' for all styles) your css: `.plugin h1 {color: blue;}`

Comment: @xadm is this not more of a workaround rather than a solution. I get your point but shouldn't web components css be encapsulated in the shadow root by default?

Comment: Above code creates a React Component, Not a W3C standard WebComponent. They are totally different things.

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman ah okay, so maybe I'm approaching it the wrong way. Any ideas on what I can do to get the latter?

Comment: at first glance here: are you even using the shadow dom? you only get the css encapsulation if you're using a true web component framework which leverages *shadow dom* -- like `lit-element` or `haunted` or `lighterhtml`

Comment: @ChaseMoskal again maybe I'm getting confused between shadow-dom and shadow-root, which is what's being rendered inside my custom element. This may be the answer but I'm unsure how to use shadow dom as the Preact documentation isnt exactly great if you ask me

Comment: if you're learning, i strongly recommend go play around with `lit-element` or one of the other new hot cool new web component microframeworks, instead of preact its old news ;)

Comment: @ChaseMoskal haha blimey Preact old news. I'm basically trying to create as small an application as possible leveraging react stuff. I had thought Preact was pretty sparse on my google searches so maybe something to have a look at thanks

Comment: (**1**) [Add a shadowRoot to the DOM element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42274721/shadow-dom-and-reactjs); kinda defeats the purpose of using (P)React (virtualDOM) and you _**can**_ run into trouble when you modify the DOM outside (P)React (virtualDOM). (**2**) Don't use (P)React, use Native __*W3C Standard CustomElements API*__ (aka WebComponents); and don't start with a Library. Learn the W3C Native Javascript way and you will be in business for as long as JavaScript is supported in the Browser. See: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-components/customelements

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman thankyou will take a look. To be fair my app was only intended to be small but did plan on having a few components so for that reason I went with a react app, to give me the bindings and whatnot off the bat.

Comment: Any Library/Framework might make your development life easier, but you are stacking technologies. Creating dependencies. No vendor will assure you their tech-stack will be maintained for the next 1000 JavaScript years. jQuery had 20 competitors 10 years ago, those who bet on the wrong horse had to ditch Mootools, YUI.. Same applies to WebComponent tech-stacks LIT, Hybrids, Stencil (and 10 more) today.  Learning WebComponents with Native code might cost 10% extra, but you will be in business for as long as JavaScript is supported in the Browser. Also see https://custom-elements-everywhere.com/

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman so from what it seems things like lit element are great for smaller web components with single js classes and little imports. For me, what I am embedding will essentially be a fully fledged web application that I'd like to just embed. This is the reason for using preact/react in the first place as it allows for easy 2way data binding and switching out of dom elements mimicking new pages etc.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you want the option `{ shadow: true }` when you register the component, as in: `register(App, 'my-widget', ['my-widget'], { shadow: true });`