# Use Shadow DOM in react project

Tags: reactjs, shadow-dom

I'm building a widget.

My widget is behaving differently on each sites, as parent website CSS is affecting widget elements.

So I'm planning to move everything to shadow DOM. But havn't worked with Shadow DOM nor my frontend skills are that good.  So would appreciate your help.

### My `App.tsx` looks like this

```
export const App = ({ element, ...appSettings }: Props) => <Main />;
```

### Main file looks like this.

`Style.root` position the widget on specific places like top-middle or bottom middle.

```
 return (
        <div>
            <div className=${style.root}>
                <div>
                    <div className={style.container}>
                        <WidgetTypes data={data}/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>:
```

`WidgetType` component looks like this

```
if(type=small)
  return <WidgetSmall>

if(type=large)
  return <WidgetLarge>
```

Since this is a widget. I want to move the entire react app into Shadow DOM.I have tried moving the app like this but not working

```
const hostContainer = document.getElementById('rootouter');

hostContainer?.attachShadow({mode:"open"}).append(...hostContainer.childNodes)

type Props = Configurations;
export const App = ({ element, ...appSettings }: Props) => <Main id="rootouter" />;
```

Comment: Perhaps https://www.wpeform.io/blog/render-react-app-shadow-dom-styled-components/ would help. As it stands it is too broad a question to answer in SO.

Comment: That's quite a broad question, moving everything to shadow DOM. There are existing questions about doing parts of it. For instance, [Shadow DOM and ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42274721/215552) asks specifically about rendering a React component into a shadow DOM... Perhaps you could help by showing what articles you've read in your research?

Comment: @HereticMonkey  this is the simple article I found -> (https://dev.to/tryeladd/preact-in-the-shadow-dom-ao8 ) and did some something but have got an error. I have updated my question with similar approach don't know if it is correct approach

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli What if I try to move the entire App component into app like (https://dev.to/tryeladd/preact-in-the-shadow-dom-ao8). I have updated the question with the changes. Does it work?

Comment: Word of warning, if you mix Frameworks with Web Components you will forever have to test your code whenever a Framework gets an update. If you go 100% vanilla JS Web Components they will run without any issues for the next 27 JS years. **You** have to do the math, developing "faster" today, can be costly in the long term. Different JQuery versions in one page run fine, will different Framework(s)/versions in one page run fine in the future?

Comment: Danny's point makes sense but, The main aim of web component is to solve the problem of reusability and if you already have a react app then I think it makes more sense to export it and maintain instead of re writing everything done in React. Cause that'd be huge work

Answer (score 0):

I achieved the same thing using webpack and Express. I used webpack to bundle everything and hosted it on a server using Express and used it into a different native web app.
You can easily figure out these things just by doing a simple Bing search about the same.
It is tedious work to set up webpack. It will occupy your couple of days but it's standard thing and helps to host entire react project in a bundle.

Comment: Besides your personal experience, please add the steps you performed to solve the issue / references