# How can I overwrite the styling that is specified using vanilla-extract globalStyle?

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components, vanilla-extract

I am working on a React app and have a CSS style configuration that affects all elements within the body. However, I have a new component that I want to add without applying this styling to it. Is there any way I can prevent this global style from affecting just that component?

```
globalStyle('body', {
  WebkitFontSmoothing: 'antialiased',
});
```

Some efforts I have tried but no use:

1. Define a new globalStyle that targeting the component by className to have WebkitFontSmoothing: 'never'
2. globalStyle('body:not(.testing)', { WebkitFontSmoothing: 'antialiased', MozOsxFontSmoothing: 'grayscale'});
3. use custom css !important

Comment: Have you tried [ShadowRoot](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ShadowRoot)?

Comment: Not yet @DengSihan not so familiar with ShadowRoot, my team is not using anything like this, is there an alternative?

Thanks for the comment

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get an isolated CSS environment which doesn't effect by the global CSS, [ShadowRoot](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ShadowRoot) could be a vanilla solution.

Using ShadowRoot in React could be easy via [react-shadow-root](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-shadow-root)

more example  [Shadow DOM and ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42275507/10519069)